# Extract noun phrases containing a specific word using Stanford Parser

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

How can I extract the noun phrase containing a specific word using the Stanford Parser. I can extract the Noun phrases using the code written in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652202/get-noun-phrase-of-subject-in-sentence-stanford-parser

However, I need to get the noun phrase that contains a specific word, However this is not as simple as doing a string search because that word can appear twice in the sentence. So I need to extract the noun phrase that contains the specific word at a specific order of the sentence. So suppose I have the sentence:

```
  String some_sentence = "The dog ran after the intruding bigger dog";
```

dog appears twice, the first time as the second word in the sentence, and the second time as the last word in the sentence. How can I extract the noun phrases that contain the first occurrence of dog?

Comment: The question you link to is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if not the most elegant, would probably be to collect the parse as a parenthesised string, pass it through a regex to recover the noun phrases, and examine each match to see if it contains the word.

This would give something of that sort:

```
String parse  = "(ROOT (S (NP (DT The) (NN dog)) (VP (VBD ran) (PP (IN after) (NP (DT the) (JJ intruding) (JJR bigger) (NN dog))))))";
String target = "dog";
String result = null;
String regex  = "\\(NP \\s (?: \\( .+? \\) )* \\)"; // an NP contains an arbitrary number of sub-phrases
Pattern patt  = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher match = patt.matcher(parse);
while(match.find() && result == null) {
    if (match.group().contains(target)) {
        result = match.group();
    }
}
if (result != null) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```